# tflearn - how to update model and save without completely retraining model

Tags: python, neural-network, tensorflow, tflearn

I am using `tflearn` to text classification.  I am able to create DNN and fit it and save it and also retrieve it for predictions.

I would like to update trained model with new test data. I checked documentation and also methods but the only way I could figure out is to call

`model.fit()` which would completely retrain the model and takes a lot of time since it is from scratch.

On other hand `model.save()` would just save the loaded model without updating new data.

Is there a function or way to update the trained model with just one data without going through whole retraining process?

## Code used to load and save model

```
model.fit(train_x, train_y, n_epoch=1000, batch_size=8, show_metric=True)
model.save('model.tflearn')
```

## Code used to retrieve and load existing model

```
tf.reset_default_graph()
# Build neural network
# train_x[0] and train_y[0] had to be regenerated from scratch
net = tflearn.input_data(shape=[None, len(train_x[0])])
net = tflearn.fully_connected(net, 8)
net = tflearn.fully_connected(net, 8)
net = tflearn.fully_connected(net, len(train_y[0]), activation='softmax')
net = tflearn.regression(net)

# Define model and setup tensorboard
dnn = tflearn.DNN(net, tensorboard_dir='tflearn_logs')
dnn.load('./model.tflearn')
```

Comment: Yes, but I dont think that `model.predict(test_data)` "retrains" or update the model, or am I wrong?

Comment: Yes you are right . calling just predict wont retrain it. And it wont update the model . It just calls the predict function to make predictions. I missed some code which had in system . will check and post new answer